# Copying the string of pointer to other pointer

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, string-literals, strcpy

Folks,
   I have basic and simple question on pointers. The below is code is giving a segmentation fault.

```
int main()

{

    char *str = "hello, world\n";

    char *strc = "good morning\n";

    strcpy(strc, str);

    printf("%s\n", strc);

    return 0;

}
```

Can't we copy from pointer to other.

2. if i have char *strc = "good morning\n", can't i do like this
   strc[5] = '.';. Why this also giving a seg fault.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked here 10,000 times. No you can't, variable `strc` is pointing to a RO memory segment within the executable image. Change `char *strc` to `char strc[]` and it will be pointing to (allocated on) the stack.

Comment: Yes, i know that. i want to know, what is the reason.

Comment: Please note that with `char strc[] = "good morning\n"`, the literal string itself will still be allocated in a RO memory segment, but every time the function is called, that string will be copied into the stack (i.e., into the `strc[]` array).

Answer (score 2):

You may not change string literals. It is what you are trying to do in statement

```
strcpy(strc, str);
```

that is you are trying to overwrite string literal "good morning\n" pointed to by pointer `strc`.

Of cource you may use pointers in function strcpy. The valid code can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "hello, world\n";

    char strc[] = "good morning\n";

    strcpy(strc, str);

    printf("%s\n", strc);

    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "hello, world\n";

    char *strc = malloc( 14 * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( strc, "good morning\n" );

    //...

    strcpy(strc, str);

    printf("%s\n", strc);

    free( strc );

    return 0;
}
```